# C# leer una línea específica de un fichero de texto

Tags: c#, file

tengo mostrar por pantalla un línea específica de un archivo .txt, en C#. Mi código hasta ahora es este:

```
while (!file.EndOfStream)
{
    counter++;

    if (counter == 4) {
        line = file.ReadLine();
        System.Console.WriteLine(line);
    }

}
```

---

También he probado con este código pero me aparece la primera línea:

```
 while (!file.EndOfStream)
{
    line = file.ReadLine();
    //System.Console.WriteLine(line);
    if (++counter ==4) break;

}
```

---

También saber a ver si se podría leer una línea específica pero detectando una cadena de carácteres.

```
Properties: 
Name=X 
Path=X 
Version=1.000
```

El archivo de texto es parecido a esto, necesito leer la versión, simplemente es para hacer unas pruebas.

Comment: No está muy clara la pregunta. En principio con tu código debería aparecer la cuarta fila del archivo. Si no es asi, estas seguro de que el archivo tiene retornos de carro? En cuanto a tu segunda pregunta, puedes poner un ejemplo de como es el archivo de texto y que cadena de caracteres quieres buscar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo lo haria asi si no son demasiadas lineas:

```
int i = 3 // siendo 3 la cuarta linea ya que cuenta desde 0
string resultado = File.ReadAllLines("ruta del fichero")[i];
```

Por ampliar la respuesta, si no supieses exactamente en que linea esta el texto que necesitas buscar lo podrias hacer tal que asi:

```
string resultado = File.ReadAllLines("ruta del fichero").Where(X => X.Contains("Texto")).First();
```

Comment: Puedes reemplazar el `.Where(X => X.Contains("Texto")).First();` por `.First(X => X.Contains("Texto"))`

Answer (score 2):

Si necesitas buscar una fila específica en un archivo de texto, lo mejor es usar [`ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) como bien recomienda Veelicus en su respuesta. De esa manera tienes en un `string[]` todo el archivo y es mas sencillo manipularlo.

En cuanto a buscar un texto en concreto, puedes hacer uso de LINQ en combinación con [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) o [`StartsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string fila = File.ReadAllLines(@"rutaDeArchivo")
                    .Where(x=>x.Contains("Version"))
                    .FirstOrDefault(); //Busca la primera fila que contenga el texto

string fila = File.ReadAllLines(@"rutaDeArchivo")
                    .Where(x=>x.StartsWith("Version"))
                    .FirstOrDefault(); //Busca la primera fila que empiece por el texto
```

Comment: quizá LINQ sea dificil de entender para este usuario, pero como añadido está bien. Un poco más cutre seria hacer un solo string con el texto y usar `indexOf` y `substring`

Comment: Teniendo LINQ, no veo porque no usarlo @lois6b ;) De todas maneras, yo no haría un solo string, simplemente con un bucle y usando igualmente `Contains` o `StartsWith` sería suficiente